# When replacing keyboard interrupt (Interrupt 9) scanf doesn't appear to accept input

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt-handling, dosbox, turbo-c

I'm writing the main program in Turbo-C and the functions are in assembly. My code is as follows:

**lastc.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string.h>
extern void  eliminate_multiple_press(); // save old function adress in 32bit     pointer
                                    // setvect , add new function to inturupt 9
extern void  uneliminate_multiple_press(); // restore old function to inturupt 9
int main()
{
char *str;
eliminate_multiple_press();
printf("Enter a string:\n");
scanf("%s",str);
printf("the string you entered:\n");
printf("%s\n",str);

uneliminate_multiple_press();

return 0;
}
```

**lasta.asm**:

```
.MODEL LARGE
PUBLIC _eliminate_multiple_press
PUBLIC _uneliminate_multiple_press

.STACK 100H
.DATA
INT9SAVE DD ?
hexa_code db 0
scan_code db 0
.CODE

KEY_HANDLER PROC FAR
PUSH AX

MOV AH,0
int 16h
mov scan_code,ah
mov hexa_code,al
POP AX
iRET
KEY_HANDLER ENDP
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
_eliminate_multiple_press PROC FAR

PUSH AX    
PUSH ES
MOV AX,0  
MOV ES,AX

;INT9SAVE = GETVECT(9);
MOV AX,ES:[9*4] ; **ax=c1 hex =193 dec**
MOV WORD PTR INT9SAVE,AX
MOV AX,ES:[9*4+2] **ax=15c7 hex = 5575 dec**
MOV WORD PTR INT9SAVE+2,AX

;SETVECT(9,KEY_HANDLER);
CLI
MOV WORD PTR ES:[9*4],OFFSET KEY_HANDLER ; **ES stays 0**
MOV WORD PTR ES:[9*4+2],SEG KEY_HANDLER ; **ES stays 0**
STI 
POP ES     
POP AX 
RET
_eliminate_multiple_press ENDP

;SETVECT(9,INT9SAVE);
_uneliminate_multiple_press PROC FAR
PUSH ES
PUSH AX
MOV AX,0
MOV ES,AX
CLI
MOV AX,WORD PTR INT9SAVE
MOV ES:[9*4],AX
MOV AX,WORD PTR INT9SAVE+2
MOV ES:[9*4+2],AX
STI
POP AX
POP ES
RET
_uneliminate_multiple_press ENDP



END
```

I can compile the files without error using this command:

```
tcc -ml -r- lastc.c lasta.asm
```

The goal of this code is to eliminate multiple (duplicate) key presses on the keyboard. If I type this sequence of characters:

> 334ffffghjjjj of my keyboard

The output on the screen should be

> 34fghj

---

### The Problem

When I run the program *lastc.exe* it gets stuck at `printf("enter a string:\n");`. I guess I'm having a problem changing Interrupt 9h interrupt service routine to my new function `key_handler`

Function `key_handler` is not complete but at least it should END the function and continue to the end of the code

Why does my program appear to be doing nothing when the `scanf` is called?

Comment: Wow, what a nostalgic post :)

Comment: P.S. you may try this code on a virtual machine with a debugger, and see what happens within eliminate_multiple_press.

Comment: i updated what happens in the debugger in eliminate_multiple_press
**i cant see in the debugger that the code jumps to key_handler function anywhere**

Comment: Why are `eliminate_multiple_press` and `uneliminate_multiple_press` declared as interrupt handlers? They should be normal functions with a return of `RET`. The only interrupt handler is `KEY_HANDLER` which these two functions manage. Also, if you want to push a bunch of registers, I recommend `pusha` and `popa`.

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362168/handling-a-keyboard-interrupt-with-turbo-c-3-0

Answer (score 2):

Why are `eliminate_multiple_press` and `uneliminate_multiple_press` declared as interrupt handlers? They should be normal functions with a return of `RET`. They are being called as functions and are not intended as responses to an interrupt.

In your C program then:

```
extern void eliminate_multiple_press(); // save old function adress in 32bit     pointer
                                    // setvect , add new function to inturupt 9
extern void uneliminate_multiple_press(); // restore old function to inturupt 9
```

And your assembly, `RET` instead of `IRET`. And you don't need to save so many registers:

```
_eliminate_multiple_press PROC FAR
    push ES
    push AX

    MOV AX,0
    MOV ES,AX

    ;INT9SAVE = GETVECT(9);
    MOV AX,ES:[9*4] ; **ax=c1 hex =193 dec**
    MOV WORD PTR INT9SAVE,AX
    MOV AX,ES:[9*4+2] **ax=15c7 hex = 5575 dec**
    MOV WORD PTR INT9SAVE+2,AX

    ;SETVECT(9,KEY_HANDLER);
    CLI
    MOV WORD PTR ES:[9*4],OFFSET KEY_HANDLER ; **ES stays 0**
    MOV WORD PTR ES:[9*4+2],SEG KEY_HANDLER ; **ES stays 0**
    STI

    POP AX
    POP ES
    RET
_eliminate_multiple_press ENDP


;SETVECT(9,INT9SAVE);
_uneliminate_multiple_press PROC FAR
    PUSH ES
    PUSH AX

    MOV AX,0
    MOV ES,AX

    CLI
    MOV AX,WORD PTR INT9SAVE
    MOV ES:[9*4],AX
    MOV AX,WORD PTR INT9SAVE+2
    MOV ES:[9*4+2],AX   ; Was "[27*4+2]" which is incorrect.
    STI

    POP AX
    POP ES
    RET

_uneliminate_multiple_press ENDP
```

Comment: so if i understand right...my key_handler should be ended with iret 
am i right on this one ?
because it is the function that got replaced with the old function of interrupt 9 @mbratch

Comment: @aminhalloun yes. `KEY_HANDLER` is your interrupt handler to replace the old one, so it needs `IRET` and to save registers (I recommend `pusha` and `popa` if you're not sure what registers `int 16h` is modifying). The functions you are calling from C are not interrupt handlers.

Comment: i updated my code up there..but still my exe flie is getting stuck at printf function!!
i cant figure out what is the problem ?

Comment: @aminhalloun The code still looks the same in C: you are declaring the called functions as `interrupt`. Also, the asm instruction `MOV ES:[27*4+2],AX` is incorrect.

Comment: it should be 9 not 27 i got confused there -updated-
but still..getting stuck :/

Comment: @aminhalloun I'm not sure what version of `KEY_HANDLER` you're testing, but the one you show in your problem statement obviously won't return the actual key pressed. So your `scanf` may not return since it needs to see a CR.

Comment: ok now i understand more, lets say i want the key_handler to act as usual ( it won't eliminate multiple press )
my idea is to use int16h,ah 0 and move the hexa code to the adress that *str points to, then by adding 4 decimal to the address
ill fill up the next "solt".
getting out of this loop is by comparing the scan code or hexa code to "enter" or "esc"

Comment: The main thing that i dont understand is how does the original int 9 work and how is it connected to scanf function and *str?

Comment: Int 9 is a hardware interrupt, invoked by irq 1 in response to a key press or key release. The only thing it "returns" is to put the keystroke (ascii code and scan code) in the keyboard buffer in the BIOS Data Area. A DOS implementation of the C library `scanf` would get keystrokes from there, probably via int 21h... unless it's redirected (myprog<infile.txt).

Answer (score -2):

An End Of Interrupt (EOI) is a signal sent to a Programmable Interrupt Controller (PIC) to
 indicate the completion of interrupt processing for a given interrupt.

```
mov al,020h ; =EOI
out 020h,al
```